# How do I provide helpful compiler errors in a procedural macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I am designing a custom HTML syntax parser using `proc_macro` and `syn`. A sample:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct BlockElement {
    stag: Ident,
    child: Vec<Element>,
    ctag: Ident
}

impl Synom for BlockElement {
     named!(parse -> Self, do_parse!(
         punct!(<) >>
         stag: syn!(Ident) >>
         punct!(>) >>
         child: syn!(ElementList) >>
         punct!(<) >>
         punct!(/) >>
         ctag: syn!(Ident) >>
         punct!(>) >>
         (BlockElement { stag, child: child.inner, ctag })
     ));
 }
```

Though I know how give out errors using `Span` after it has been parsed, I am not able to figure how to do it during a parse. It just errors out with `failed to parse anything`. How to pin-point where parsing failed and give appropriate error?

Comment: I'm not quiet sure, what your main concern is, does [trace_macros!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/trace-macros.html) and [log_syntax!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/log-syntax.html) may help you?

Comment: My main concern is that the users of this macro will have to look for themselves for any error in the custom syntax. I would like the parser to display where the error occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By upgrading your macro to use [Syn 0.15](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn/releases/tag/0.15.0) or greater, you get helpful parse error messages with no additional effort.

```
extern crate proc_macro;
use self::proc_macro::TokenStream;

use syn::parse::{Parse, ParseStream, Result};
use syn::{parse_macro_input, Ident, Token};

// FIXME
type Element = Ident;

struct ElementList {
    inner: Vec<Element>,
}

impl Parse for ElementList {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        let mut list = Vec::new();
        while let Some(element) = input.parse()? {
            list.push(element);
        }
        Ok(ElementList { inner: list })
    }
}

struct BlockElement {
    stag: Ident,
    child: Vec<Element>,
    ctag: Ident
}

impl Parse for BlockElement {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        input.parse::<Token![<]>()?;
        let stag: Ident = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<Token![>]>()?;
        let child: ElementList = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<Token![<]>()?;
        input.parse::<Token![/]>()?;
        let ctag: Ident = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<Token![>]>()?;
        Ok(BlockElement { stag, child: child.inner, ctag })
    }
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn html_syntax(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let _input = parse_macro_input!(input as BlockElement);

    // TODO
    TokenStream::new()
}
```

Here is an example of an input parse error. Such errors will indicate where the input failed to parse and what token(s) the macro would have expected in that position.

```
fn main() {
    html_syntax!(<em>syn quote proc_macro2<em>);
}
```

```
error: expected `/`
 --> src/main.rs
  |
  |     html_syntax!(<em>syn quote proc_macro2<em>);
  |                                            ^^
```